# jquery sortable: nested lists: move sublist items between sublists, but do not create new list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have jquery sortable lists within lists. In the example below, I want to move items between sublists, but sublists items must remain in a sublist.

Also, the Mary and Peter categories should be sortable with respect to each other.

```
Stuff Mary does
    get food
    find dj
Stuff Peter does
    make drinks
    play piano
```

I have:

```
<ul id="s1">
    <li>Stuff Mary does
        <ul id="s2" > 
          <li > get food  </li> 
          <li >find dj  </li> 
        </ul>
    </li> 
    <li >Stuff Peter does
        <ul id="s3" > 
          <li > make drinks  </li> 
          <li >play piano  </li> 
        </ul>
    </li> 
</ul>

$( "#s1, #s2, #s3" ).sortable();
```

This keeps sublist items as sublist items, but they cannot move between the two lists. If the ul's have the same id, then sublist items can move within sublists, but they can also (permanently) become lists. Giving the sublists the same id, separate from the parent, also does not work.

Comment: giving similar id's is not acceptable and it will make your code unstable.
Can you provide a js fiddle to show us how your code works?

Comment: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VVEUq/.